# Yii2 error in gii code generator for mongodb: no such cmd: listCollections

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I have installed mongodb extension in yii2 and trying to do the CRUD operation through gii tool. But I am getting following error.

```
MongoDB Exception – yii\mongodb\Exception
no such cmd: listCollections

Caused by: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException
no such cmd: listCollections

in /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/Command.php at line 187
```